# Reducing execution time for the following query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

How can I reduce time for the following query?

```
SELECT *
FROM (`ci_session`)
WHERE `session_id` = '8011e978d8692846a22bc8f7f806af4d'
AND `user_agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0) Gecko/2010010'
```

This query takes around 0.3 seconds to execute on my MySQL 5.5

This is an very important query as it determines the session of the user (PHP/CodeIgniter)

The table contains 1000 rows.

Comment: do you have an index on those columns already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_id` is a fixed with column, try to change it to `CHAR(32)` instead of `VARCHAR` if that's the case.

And make a `UNIQUE INDEX` for session_id.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_session ON ci_session (session_id)
```

Or an `INDEX` with prefix

```
CREATE INDEX idx_session ON ci_session (session_id(8))
```

and change the length of the prefix to see which one is faster.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of easy wins to start with...

1. Select specific columns, not *
2. Add an index for the session_id and user_agent columns

Comment: The index on `user_agent` won't ever be used. The one on `session_id` will be more selective.

Comment: Fair point, but I long ago gave up applying toooo much logic to how database engines use/ignore indexes :-) I wouldn't be surprised to see it ignore the index if multiple columns are used and the index only applies to one. (Seen it before on SQL server)

Comment: Such an event typically occurs when the single column index is selective enough to return a small set of rows by itself. Reading it in place of the multi-column one alongside a filter then takes less memory. :-)

Comment: Performance on an index that contains all the information needed to be returned can be up to 10 times faster than an index that only finds the row and then has to find the information to return in that row. It's definitely worth it for performance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `ci_session` table has an index on `session_id` (or that the latter is the primary key). There isn't much more that you can do to make it faster.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to select *?

If you just need the username, only select that. Then add a composite index to the table:

```
user_agent, session_id, username
```

By including username in the index, it should be able to return the query directly from the index without looking up the row in the table.

Also, do you really need to filter on user_agent? Is the session_id not unique?

Answer (score 1):

Integer matching is always faster than string matching (and will almost always have lower storage requirements) so try using integer session IDs instead of the strings you're using now.

Shorter strings are faster to match than longer strings, and fixed width strings are also a bit better than variable length ones (varchars)  so you might consider applying a hashing function to the user agent and storing it in a fixed-width char field.  Then match the MD5 of the agent string against the MD5 of the stored one.

Last, but by no means least, indexing can provide a massive speedup for queries, so consider what your indexes are and add appropriate ones if an index seems like it would speed the query up.  Using EXPLAIN SELECT will help you determine where queries can be sped up with indexes.